# Facebook Graph API Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebooks graph api on my blog for users to leave comments and view comments for a article there viewing, ive looked at there graph api page and I'm always getting an error 'unauthorised post request'

I have request publish_stream and status_update when users accept my app via fbconnect, I'm using similar code as below to post a comment:

```
facebook -> api('/http://www.mysite.com/blog/article-title-here/likes', 
   'post', 
   array(
      'id' => 'http://www.mysite.com/blog/article-title-here',
      'message' => 'users comment',
      'created_time' => PHP_DATE_FUNCTION
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way...

You can only use the publish method to publish on a user's, page's, group's wall. You can't pass an id around like that:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

As an alternative way, you might want to look into the comment box plugin that facebook offers:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments

-Roozbeh

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply,

Ive used the comments plugin but when a user selects post to my wall aswell the format it posts didnt match what I was looking for, I want it to post like posting a link: title, link, thumbnail and message (which ive been able to produce using graph api).

I was hopeing the api system would allow me to create comments like the plugin does with my own form and check box for posting to users wall.

Is there no way we are able to do this?

Regards, Mark

Answer (score 0):

```
facebook -> api('/'.$post_id.'/comments', 
   'post', 
   array(
      'message' => 'users comment',
   )
);
```

i think you you need to use latest facebook graph api if you are try to post comment on posts or photo then use this